# How to access env variables from phpunit.xml rather than app config file

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

*Note: It is important to understand that the way the constants in my problem are defined are significantly different to those in the question flagged to be a duplicate of my question, because mine are config file oriented as opposed to env file oriented.*

I am writing integration test cases where I don't want to provide my app key from the config file but want it to get accessed from a phpunit.xml file.

But it still accesses the keys from a config file and not from a phpunit.xml file.
I have tried the force element as well.
 What needs to be done in this regard?

**Config file:**

```
 <?php

 return [
    'KEY' => env('Test', ''),
    'DATA' => env('Test1', '')
 ];
```

**phpunit.xml file:**

```
 <php>
     <env name="Test" value="foo" />
     <env name="Test1" value="secret"/>
 </php>
```